# How to make bootstrap 4 drop down with json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a input field with drop-down button inside a form i am trying to make that drop-down to store the values dynamically,here i have static JSON data from which i am trying to make the drop-down,but its not working properly

- the data is showing inside the drop-down list
- i have written a code for which dropdown is clicked should gets populated inside the input field
- my data populating inside input field from drop-down is correct
- my code to load dropdown is wrong i think

**Code Snippet**

```js
$(".dropdown-item").click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".input-group").find("input").val($(this).text())
});
var data = [{
    "code": "1234",
    "name": "banana"
  },
  {
    "code": "5678",
    "name": "apple"
  },
  {
    "code": "9635",
    "name": "grapes"
  }
]
let dropdown = $('#itemCode');
dropdown.empty();
$.each(data, function(key, entry) {
  dropdown.append($('<a class="dropdown-item"></a>').attr('value', entry.code).text(entry.name));

});
$("#itemCode").on("change", function(e) {
  var selectedOption = this.value;
  alert(selectedOption)
});
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-row">
    <hr>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="itemCode">Item Code</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"></button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="itemCode">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

here i think my code to populate drop-down field is wrong,that's why it is not working fine

please anyone out here help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's just that your click event is in the wrong place - it never gets assigned, move it to here:

```
$.each(data, function(key, entry) {
  dropdown.append( $('<a class="dropdown-item"></a>')
    .attr('value', entry.code).text(entry.name).click(function() {
          $(this).closest(".input-group").find("input").val($(this).text())
     })

);
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are wanting to do is create a dropdown lsit in jquery and send it to a html tag then you can do this.

Inside `<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="itemCode">` have a select tag such as this.

```
<select class="form-control" data-val="true" id="//ID of dropdown" name="//Whatever"></select>
```

Your javascript code will look something like this. We will be simply craeting markup and inserting it into the select tag.

```
            //Markup for drop down list
            var markup = "<option Value='0'>Select option</option>";

            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                markup += "<option Value=" + result[i].Value + ">" + result[i].Text + "</option>";
            }

            //Populate dropdown with value
            $("#//ID of the Select").html(markup).show();
```

The above javascript is what I have done when I have returned data from an Ajax however to suit your needs you could simply loop through `data` and insert the correct value into the markup